# How to move items in flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I would like to move all the items in the class "right" to the far right of the browser but still in the same line with the class "left". I have use justify-content: flex-end but it seem doesn't work. Reference in link https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev8uV.jpg

```css
body{
font-family: sans-serif;
color: black;
height: 100vh;
}
.navbar h3{
    border:1px #ccc solid;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.left{
    display: inline-flex;
}
.right{
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;    
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="left">
                <h3>ABOUT</h3>
                <h3>CONTACT</h3>
                <h3>FAQS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <h3>MANAGE BOOKING</h3>
                <h3>SIGN IN</h3>
                <h3>REGISTER</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <div>Find your ideal car from 500+</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `navbar` class should be `display: flex` with `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
body{
font-family: sans-serif;
color: black;
height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar h3{
    border:1px #ccc solid;
}

.left{
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: left;
}

.right{
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: right;    
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="left">
                <h3>ABOUT</h3>
                <h3>CONTACT</h3>
                <h3>FAQS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <h3>MANAGE BOOKING</h3>
                <h3>SIGN IN</h3>
                <h3>REGISTER</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <div>Find your ideal car from 500+</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Here's a Codepen of a more complex example](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/vWEMWw), which is from [this CSS-Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.right{
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;  
}
```

Comment: You need to indicate that this is a flex box and you do that by setting the setting of the container to flex. display: flex. After that you can move the elements along the X/Y axis.

Comment: But this will made the class "right" to stay on another line. Is there a way to made class "left" and "right" on the same line?